# Remove specific words/strings from the list

Tags: java, arrays, string, date

How can we remove and preserve only Date from a String:

```
For ex: String outPut = {Time = 0:0:0} {Timestamp = Tue Oct 20 23:54:10 BST 2013}
```

I would like to have only Date

```
For ex: Tue Oct 20 2013
```

So far, I have tried the following approach:

```
String[] manipulateDate = output.getDate().split("\\{");
        for(String s : manipulateDate ){
            String outputDate = manipulateDate [2].replaceAll("\\}", "").replaceAll("\\s*\\bTimestamp =\\b\\s*","");
                System.out.println(outputDate );
        }
```

What is the best way to implement and use Java Date/String?

Comment: Unclear what you input is. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question, you could do:

```
String date = output.replaceAll(".*Timestamp = (.*)? \\d{2}:.*?(\\d{4}).*", "$1 $2");
```

But it may be preferable to parse the whole string as a date object:

```
String output = "{Time = 0:0:0} {Timestamp = Sun Oct 20 23:54:10 BST 2013}";
String timestamp = output.replaceAll("\\{.*?\\} \\{Timestamp = (.*)\\}", "$1"); //Sun Oct 20 23:54:10 BST 2013
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(timestamp, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

From that point on, you can do what you want with the date object, including printing it as a string. Note that I changed the original string to Sunday (vs. Tuesday in your question): parsing it as a date also caught the fact that the 20th of October 2013 was not a Thursday, another advantage over strings.

Comment: Thanks! What if we don't want to use ZonedDateTime? Can we get plain Date for ex: 2014-01-01

Comment: Sure: `dateTime.toLocalDate()`